# One of the cron jobs not running

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I have tried a lot many things but I cannot seem to get it to work.
I have the following 2 entries in my cron:

```
00 21 * * 0,2,4 /scratch/.auto_preflight/sys_reboot.pl >> /scratch/.auto_preflight/.auto_reboot.log 2>&1

30 21 * * 0,2,4 /scratch/.auto_preflight/check_new_build.pl /scratch/.auto_preflight/import.txt >> /scratch/.auto_preflight/.auto_buildcheck.log 2>&1
```

When I check after the execution, I can see the first script executed successfully. It reboots the system. I can see the logs and everything. But the script supposed to execute a job half an hour later is not running for some reason. Doesn't even leave any logs.

Now I have tried changing time and restarting cron, it runs then, but it is not running at the scheduled time. Does system restart hinder cron jobs to execute in some way?

Here is my cron version:
     vixie-cron-4.1-81.el5

Comment: Does the file `/scratch/.auto_preflight/check_new_build.pl` exist? 

The only way I can see the 2nd job not run is if the system is ready from reboot later than 30 minute mark of the hour than when the reboot started.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The system comes back up after 10 minutes tops and yes the perl script exists in the specified path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron always leaves logs: what does /var/log/cron say? do you see your entry there attempting to run?

When does machine come up after reboot? Is that a case of a really long reboot? Some scripts hold up the shutdown/startup?

Also check for other entries from the same timeframe in /var/log/cron.

Stab in the dark: is SELinux on? Based on your description it shouldn't matter, but for example if your machine starts with Enforcing mode yet something changes it to Permissive later on - that could be something to look into. So the state of /etc/sysconfig/selinux is important here, as well as output of "sestatus" command when you can successfully execute your job by adjusting the time.

Looking at /var/log/audit/audit.log may shed some light on it in case of SELinux issues.

Last thing: simplify the problem and instead of "special" scripts - create "dummy" scripts:

```
00 21 * * 0,2,4 reboot
30 21 * * 0,2,4 touch /tmp/foo
```

now if /tmp/foo doesn't exist - something is screwed with the system, otherwise it must be some logic in scripts that is failing (lock files etc.) There is no reason cron wouldn't run job on account of reboot. That would prevent all other cron jobs from ever firing.

Comment: The cron logs look fine. I do not see any errors or any script names. sestatus returns disabled status. One more thing, so I changed the time for the second job to a few minutes later than my current time and restarted cron. It picked up the job. This makes me suspect something's wrong with the system or cron service.

Comment: you should probably use pastebin or some other service to publish the logs.

Comment: looking at the logs I can't find a single instance of invocation for your scripts (neither reboot nor check_new_build).

Comment: cron will always pick up "new" jobs a minute or two later than you created them. It rescans for new jobs every minute but I believe it doesn't apply it right away and it will be able to run it only on the next minute so there are 2m right there.

Comment: which log do you add those entries to? some user/root crontab? /etc/crontab . perhaps adding it to /etc/cron.d would yeild better results (in my case SELinux contexts worked differently for /etc/cron.d entries vs /etc/cron.{hourly,daily,...} vs crontab -e ... however you have selinux disabled so that shouldn't be the case

Comment: Thank you folks. I swapped the entries making check_new_build run first. Although this fixed the issue, I still do not understand why reboot running first would cause this.